# Unable to install Vagrant_1.7.4

Tags: vagrant

I am unable to install the software Vagrant_1.7.4, that is Nothing happens

Steps:

1) I have **Windows Vista** Laptop, I downloaded `Vagrant_1.7.4.msi`, I am unable to install the file, Right--click on Install does nothing.

2) I have disabled Windows Firewall and **360 Total Security**, and tried the same, still it is Status Quo

Comment: The first thing to do is delete the installer, and download a new copy.  Glitches do happen during downloads.

Comment: Have you tried opening Command Prompt, going to the folder where the msi is, and typing in `msiexec Vagrant_1.7.4.msi`?

Answer (score 0):

Solution

Install via command line using the following code:

msiexec /i C:\Users\username\Documents\shell\vagrant_1.7.4.msi /passive /norestart

and then restart the computer manually for the effect to take place